# What is Tangle ? It is related to blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

The blockchain is the emerging technology these days and there are many ways to learn it from many resources but I want to learn tangle as well. 
I want to learn about Tangle so where I can find resources for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Iota](https://iota.org).  The [whitepaper is a good place to start.](http://iotatoken.com/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf)

Another one is [Hedera Hashgraph](https://www.hederahashgraph.com/).  There is a link to the whitepaper on the page.